# How to filter NDB entities having exactly the same repeated properties?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

My NDB model class has repeated property:

```
class Something(ndb.Model):
  tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

Is there any way to query for all entities havings `tags` equal to `['music', 'cinema']`? I.e. each entity returned should have `music` and `cinema` tag at the same time and shouldn't have other `tags`. [The GAE doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#repeated_properties) says that

> You cannot compare repeated properties to list objects (the Datastore
> won't understand it)

Will I have to fetch all entities with one tag and then filter it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a serialized/hashed version of the list and querying for an exact match against that will likely be more efficient than fetching all of your entities:

```
class Something(ndb.Model):
  tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
  tagset = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: ','.join(self.tags.sort()))
```

Then to query use the same serialization on your search-tags:

```
    q = Something.query(cls.tagset == ','.join(sorted(['music', 'cinema'])))
```

Comment: I could be missing something, but sort() returns None, causing a 'join only works on iterable's error'.   So calling sorted(['music', 'cinema']), which returns a sorted list, may be better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `IN` property, which uses a list object when [Querying for Repeated Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#repeated_properties):

```
Something.tags.IN(['music', 'cinema'])
```

To see if both tags are present, you can use the `AND` operation:

```
Something.tags.query(ndb.AND(Something.tags == 'music',
                             Something.tags == 'cinema'))
```

Comment: I think this is a legit answer too. down votes for no reason